# How to save data in excel file MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to save pitch,yaw and roll data in excel file for all frames. Eg: if i have 200 frames then i want to save 200 frames information in excel file. I have tried but my code only stores one frame data.[exceldata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VutCh.png)

```
fitting_model='models/Chehra_f1.0.mat';
load(fitting_model);     
mov=VideoReader('7_a.avi'); %Read video file and create an object
c=mov.NumberOfFrames;
for k=1:c
    a = read(mov, k);
    img=im2double(a);           
    disp(['Detecting Face in ']);
    faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector(); % detect face in an image
    bbox = step(faceDetector, img);                %create boundary box around face
    test_init_shape = InitShape(bbox,refShape);    %initialize facial points in variable
    test_init_shape = reshape(test_init_shape,49,2);
    if size(img,3) == 3
        test_input_image = im2double(rgb2gray(img));
    else
        test_input_image = im2double((img));
    end
    disp(['Fitting']);    
    MaxIter=6;
    test_points = Fitting(test_input_image,test_init_shape,RegMat,MaxIter);
load('3D_Shape_Model.mat');
n=49;
    test_image=img;
    imshow(test_image);hold on;
        % % Compute 3D Head Pose
    if(n==49)
        test_shape=test_points;
        [pitch,yaw,roll] = ComputePose(PDM_49,test_shape(:));
          filename='framesdata.xlsx';
        header = {'Pitch', 'yaw ','roll'};
        new_data = num2cell([pitch(:), yaw(:), roll(:)]);
        output = [header; new_data];
        xlswrite(filename,output);
    end     
    plot(test_shape(:,1),test_shape(:,2),'b*');
    title([num2str(i),' : Pitch = ',num2str(pitch),' ; Yaw = ',num2str(yaw),' ; Roll = ',num2str(roll)]);
    set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
    pause(0.5);
    close all;
end
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of `output`?

Comment: In current situation workspace shows 2x3 cell as output dimension..

Comment: So where does the 144 frames come into it?

Comment: Those frames read from video sequence mov=VideoReader('7_a.avi'); 
c=mov.NumberOfFrames;

Comment: So then you need to include that in your question! Are you using a loop or something? Please read up on and create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @usman you are writing to the same location (`A1`, by default) in your excel file each time you call `xlswrite`. You either need to store your results differently and make a single `xlswrite` call at the end or iterate your row location as you loop.

Answer (score 0):

As @excaza stated, you will need to move the xlswrite command out of your loop or specify the cells you are writing. Please see the [xlswrite Doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) for more information. The correct syntax would be :

```
xlswrite(filename,A,xlRange)
```

The following is the example they provide:

```
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';
A = {'Time','Temperature'; 12,98; 13,99; 14,97};
sheet = 2;
xlRange = 'E1';
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)
```

You will just need to provide xlswrite the address to start writing data.